# Given some N, find the i for which φ(i)/i is the largest among all 2≤i≤N.

Tags: number-theory, totient-function

For some N, let P be the largest prime less than or equal to N, and C be some composite number less than or equal to N.If we have proved that φ(C)/C < ((P - 1) / P) then how can we say that φ(C)/C < φ(P)/P? The problem is in with reference to
https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/9723/witmath-editorial

Comment: Do you actually know what $\varphi(P)$ is when $P$ is a prime?

Comment: @Erick Wong yes it is p-1

Comment: @ErickWong YES i got it simply substitute p-1 with euler(p)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of comment of ERICK ,we just need to substitute p-1 with phi(p) as phi(p) for any prime p is p-1.